# Show that vectors are in an affine plane if and only if $\det=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, determinant, affine-geometry

> Let $ \mathbb{K} $ be a field and, $ a=\left(\begin{array}{l}{a_{1}} \\ {a_{2}} \\ {a_{3}}\end{array}\right), b=\left(\begin{array}{l}{b_{1}} \\ {b_{2}} \\ {b_{3}}\end{array}\right), c=\left(\begin{array}{c}{c_{1}} \\ {c_{2}} \\ {c_{3}}\end{array}\right), d=\left(\begin{array}{c}{d_{1}} \\ {d_{2}} \\ {d_{3}}\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{K}^{3} $
>
> Show that $a,b,c,d$ are in an affine plane if and only if
>
> $det\left(\begin{array}{llll}
> {a_{1}} & {b_{1}} & {c_{1}} & {d_{1}} \\
> {a_{2}} & {b_{2}} & {c_{2}} & {d_{2}} \\
> {a_{3}} & {b_{3}} & {c_{3}} & {d_{3}} \\
> {1} & {1} & {1} & {1}
> \end{array}\right)=0$

How can I show this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can someone give me another hint? I am still not entirely sure how to solve this.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3516437/265466 and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinent is $\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
b_1-a_1 & & \\
b_2-a_2& \cdots & \cdots \\
b_3-a_3& & 
\end{array}\right)=0$. Then the linear subspace $U=\operatorname{span}(b-a,c-a,d-a)$ has rank 0,1 or 2.

I think affine plane is defined to be $p+V=\{p+v\mid v\in V\}$, where the point $p$ is in affine space and $V$ is a linear vector (sub)space. So if $\operatorname{rank}(U)=2$, then $a+U$ is a two dimension affine plane and $a,b,c,d\in a+U$. If $\operatorname{rank}(U)\le 1$, $a+U$ is a affine line or point, which can contain in a plane that pass the origin $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: How did you come up with $\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
b_1-a_1 & & \\
b_2-a_2& \cdots & \cdots \\
b_3-a_3& & 
\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: I am still not quite sure how to continue. Can you elaborate on that a little bit? I am relatively new at this.